# Perl Script doesn't update file

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy, perl, script, rrdtool

I have problem with perl script. It works fine if i don't change destination path, but when I do in doesn't update my file in that destination. I got this script from web, but I want to change destination.

Updating works fine when its like this

```
 $rrd_out = '/usr/bin/rrdtool update /home/pi/temperature/rPItemp.rrd N:$temperature';
```

But when I change path to this

```
$rrd_out = '/usr/bin/rrdtool update /dev/shm/rPItemp.rrd N:$temperature';
```

I have created rrd file in that destination, but don't understand why it's not updating. Even from terminal I can see that this file executes and prints values but doesn't update that file in /dev/shm/rPItemp.rrd

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: It is obvious why it doesn't work. Only root has permission. Why do you want to put logged data into a directory reserved for devices? If you search this Forum you will find examples of others who have plotted temperature with rrdtool.

Comment: That's because I don't want to write data in my sd card all the time. I have other scripts witch does not mind to write data there, but this does. I even made new per scripts that just make new file there and write a something. But why this doesn't?

Comment: The other script probably elevates itself in some way using 'sudo', maybe you could try using `$rrd_out = 'sudo /usr/bin/rrdtool update /dev/shm/rPItemp.rrd N:$temperature';`

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If so, please mark the answer that helped you, or if you solved it on your own, create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the site Q:A ratio up and marking answers is what does that. If you resolved it and mark then people in the future will be able to profit from what you did *and* it helps move the site closer to graduation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're running an RRD with updates every few minutes, SD card wear won't be a problem in any reasonable amount of time.

But if you're determined to use an off-disk store, you can make a 1MB ramdisk this way:

```
sudo mkdir -m777 /mnt/scratch
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1M tmpfs /mnt/scratch
```

Anything written to a file in /mnt/scratch won't hit the SD card. I don't know if a megabyte will be big enough for your database; try it.

If you want to have this ramdisk created at boot, add the following line to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs /mnt/scratch tmpfs size=1M 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the user you're running the perl script under have permissions to modify the path ?
Can you run `ls -l /dev/shm` and post the output ?
As a test, you can run chmod 777 /dev/shm/rPItemp.rrd and see if the script can update it then.

**Edit**
After reading some comments, if you don't want to keep writing to the SD Card, I'd recommend using a separate ramdisk with read/write permissions for everyone rather than putting into /dev/shm.

Comment: It has permissions rwxrwxrwx. But I should see if it modifies this file under properties and Last Modification right?
I have another script that writes file there, and it works fine, and I can see that that files is modified

Comment: What permissions on the directory /dev/shm ?